# How to LEFT JOIN, to create a Date Range?

Tags: mysql

i have this query

```
SELECT userId, orgQuery.timeUnit, 
  @SUM := @SUM + orgQuery.orderValue AS sum, 
  @COUNT := @COUNT + 1 AS count, 
  @AVG := @SUM / @COUNT AS avg
    FROM (
    SELECT userid, orderValue,  
      DATE_FORMAT(`acceptDate`, '%Y%M') AS timeUnit
FROM `agreements` 
    WHERE userId = 4 
    AND acceptDate > 2000-00-00 
   GROUP BY timeUnit
)
AS orgQuery, 
  (SELECT @COUNT := 0, @SUM := 0,@AVG :=0) 
 AS extra GROUP BY timeUnit
```

Output:

```
userId  timeUnit    sum count   avg
4         201001    6000    1   6000.0000
4         201003    12000   2   6000.0000
4         201004    19500   3   6500.0000
```

But as you can see, there is a gap between some dates and I want the output to be a contiguous range eg:

```
userId  timeUnit    sum count   avg
4         201001    6000    1   6000.0000
4         201002    0       2   3000.0000
4         201003    12000   3   6000.0000
4         201004    19500   4   4875.0000
```

This Query

```
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`acceptDate`, '%Y%M') AS timeUnit FROM `agreements` GROUP BY timeUnit )
```

Outputs the full date range, but when I try to LEFT JOIN the two Querys, the count and avg gets all messed up. How can I get the result am looking for?

Comment: Does the table `agreements` have field value 201002 of the timeUnit? The query could be depend on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are missing an entry in your agreements table for 2012-02, it's always good to have a table containing simply dates.

```
CREATE TABLE dates(`date` date primary key);

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertDates;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insertDates()
BEGIN
SET @start_date = '2010-01-01';
WHILE (@start_date <= '2010-12-31') DO
INSERT INTO dates VALUES (@start_date);
SET @start_date:=DATE_ADD(@start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL insertDates();
```

Adjust the date range according to your needs.

Then you can write your query like the following. I simplified it a bit, since I saw no need for your variables or the subquery.

```
SELECT userId, DATE_FORMAT(dates.`date`, '%Y%M') AS timeUnit, 
  SUM(orderValue), 
  COUNT(orderValue),
  AVG(orderValue)
FROM 
dates LEFT JOIN
`agreements` ON dates.date = agreements.acceptDate
  WHERE userId = 4 
  AND acceptDate > '2000-00-00'
GROUP BY userId, timeUnit
```

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT userId, orgQuery.timeUnit, 
  @SUM := @SUM + orgQuery.orderValue AS sum, 
  @COUNT := @COUNT + 1 AS count, 
  @AVG := @SUM / @COUNT AS avg
    FROM (
    SELECT userid, orderValue,  
      DATE_FORMAT(dates.`date`, '%Y%M') AS timeUnit
FROM dates LEFT JOIN
`agreements` ON dates.date = agreements.acceptDate
    WHERE userId = 4 
    AND acceptDate > '2000-00-00' 
   GROUP BY timeUnit
)
AS orgQuery, 
  (SELECT @COUNT := 0, @SUM := 0,@AVG :=0) 
 AS extra GROUP BY timeUnit
```

Comment: If i use your solution and remove the variables, i get count / avg and sum per month, i need to get it cumulative are there a way around that?

Comment: @Robin Sorry, I don't get what you want. In your query you get the data per month, too. It should be the same result.

Comment: Only the date is per Month the sum for example  is the sum added to the  sum of last month and the month before that and so on.

Comment: @Robin Then you will have to use variables. See updated answer.